# Run pm2 commands on the server using execa (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, pm2

The task is to write a utility for deploying the NodeJS application. Requirement is to run the utility from any computer. The problem is that pm2 does not take in mind that I have switched the working directory to the server:

```
process.chdir ('SERVER');
process.cwd (); // SERVER
```

But commands run on my workstation. Share furioku, how to let pm2 know that commands need to be run on the server?

Comment: process.chdir(dir) changes the working directory of the running node.js application (https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory).  So, your code is changing the working directory to "SERVER", not to the actual server

Comment: yeah, but when I run other commands, git status/git pull etc., it works fine, but not for pm2

Comment: Where is the node.js application running?  Is it on the server or on your local computer?

Comment: app running on my local computer

Comment: The app will have to SSH to the server to send commands on the server.  I'm guessing the "other commands" you mentioned are actually just executing on your local computer.

Comment: No, "other commands" run on server, i'm sure about it.